# While loop checker never ends using logical or

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a checker for the NIN but the while loop never finishes even if the user gives the right letters. Im not sure if I have used the logical OR right.

```
   System.out.println("Give the Doctor's 9Digit National Insurance Number");
   scanner.nextLine();
   String temp1 = scanner.nextLine(); 

   while((temp1.charAt(0)=='D' || temp1.charAt(0)=='F' || temp1.charAt(0)=='I' || 
           temp1.charAt(0)=='Q'|| temp1.charAt(0)=='U' || temp1.charAt(0)=='V' || Character.isDigit(temp1.charAt(0))) 
           ||
           (temp1.charAt(1)=='D' || temp1.charAt(1)=='F' || temp1.charAt(1)=='I' || 
           temp1.charAt(1)=='Q'|| temp1.charAt(1)=='U' || temp1.charAt(1)=='V' ||
           temp1.charAt(1)=='O'|| Character.isDigit(temp1.charAt(1)))
           ||
           (!Character.isDigit(temp1.charAt(2)) || !Character.isDigit(temp1.charAt(3)) || 
            !Character.isDigit(temp1.charAt(4)) || !Character.isDigit(temp1.charAt(5)) ||
            !Character.isDigit(temp1.charAt(6)) || !Character.isDigit(temp1.charAt(7)))
           ||
           (temp1.charAt(8)!='A' || temp1.charAt(8)!='B' || temp1.charAt(8)!='C' || temp1.charAt(8)!='D')
         )
   {
       System.out.println("THE RIGHT FORMAT OF NIN IS: ");
       System.out.println("2 PREFIX LETTERS THEN 6 DIGITS & 1 SUFIX LETTER");
       System.out.println("PREFIX LETTERS CANNOT BE D, F, I, Q, U or V & 2ND PREFIX CANNOT BE O");
       System.out.println("SUFIX LETTERS CAN ONLY BE A, B, C, D");
       System.out.println("Give NIN in the right Format!");


       temp1 = scanner.nextLine(); 

   }

   String dNin = temp1 ;`
```

Comment: I don't know this code, but I could say one thing - this is not the correct way of programming.

Comment: Firstly, please minimize your stop condition like using boolean variable .... Then how do you think about using `Regex`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the last part of your loop:
(temp1.charAt(8)!='A' || temp1.charAt(8)!='B' || temp1.charAt(8)!='C' || temp1.charAt(8)!='D')
This part will always be true. For example if that letter would be A, then temp1.charAt(8)!='B' would be true, and vice versa. The following would be correct:

!(temp1.charAt(8)='A' || temp1.charAt(8)='B' || temp1.charAt(8)='C' || temp1.charAt(8)='D')

Answer (score 0):

In `while` function,

```
(temp1.charAt(8)!='A' || temp1.charAt(8)!='B' || temp1.charAt(8)!='C' || temp1.charAt(8)!='D')
```

should be

```
(temp1.charAt(8)!='A' && temp1.charAt(8)!='B' && temp1.charAt(8)!='C' && temp1.charAt(8)!='D')
```

in your logic

> "SUFIX LETTERS CAN ONLY BE A, B, C, D"

.

And using regular exception to do that is simply.
you may need import `java.util.regex.*`